# One to many relationships

Tags: excel, vba

Hope you're all well. I had a macro that I thought was working that was supposed to help me clean up an organize some data upon the following lines. I would receive sets of data that contained a SKU and a country in it, and sometimes these would be duplicates, sometimes not. They would come out like this:

- 123456       France
- 123456       Spain
- 123456       Austria
- 123444       Spain
- 123444       Austria
- 123444       England

the final product should come out like this.

- 123456   France, Spain, Austria
- 123444 Spain, Austria, England

However, I'm getting results that it shouldn't be displaying. Some countries that should be showing for certain SKUs ARE showing. Not enough SKUs are showing up (there are 66 unique SKUs, but there are over 100k lines.) I'm not clear on what is wrong with this macro. Can someone please give it a look for me?

```
Sub CondenseData()

Dim Cell    As Range
Dim Data()  As Variant
Dim Dict    As Object
Dim Key     As String
Dim index   As Long
Dim Item    As String
Dim Rng     As Range
Dim Wks     As Worksheet

    ' // Change the Worksheet and Range for your needs.
    Set Wks = ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Wks.Range("A1", Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

    ReDim Data(1 To Rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 2)

    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        ' // Ignore case.
        Dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

        ' // Step through cells and collect the data.
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            Key = Trim(Cell)            ' // Column "A" value.
            Item = Cell.Offset(0, 1)    ' // Column "B" value.

            ' // Skip empty cells.
            If Key <> "" Then
                ' // Has the SKU be added?
                If Not Dict.exists(Key) Then
                    ' // New SKU, increment the Data index.
                    index = index + 1
                    ' // Save the SKU and country on first discovery.
                    Data(index, 1) = Key
                    ' // Remove leading and trailing spaces. Capitalize the first letter of the country.
                    Data(index, 2) = Application.Proper(Trim(Item))
                    ' // Save the SKU and it's position in the Data array.
                    Dict.Add Key, index
                Else
                    ' // SKU repeat discovered, get the country.
                    index = Dict(Key)
                    ' // Exclude any repeats of the country, ignore case.
                    If InStr(1, Data(index, 2), Item, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        ' // Update the country list.
                        Data(index, 2) = Data(index, 2) & "," & Item
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next Cell

    ' // Clear the original data and replace it with the condensed data.
    Set Rng = Rng.Resize(ColumnSize:=2)
    Rng.ClearContents
    Rng.Value = Data
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `index` as an incrementing counter for new SKU's:

```
' // New SKU, increment the Data index.
index = index + 1
```

but you also re-use it to locate the "current item" - that throws off your count...

```
' // SKU repeat discovered, get the country.
index = Dict(Key)
```

use a different variable like `indx` for the second use.

Also you can move the Application.Proper to the top of the loop:

```
Item = Application.Proper(Trim(Cell.Offset(0, 1)))
```

you currently only use it when adding new dictionary items, but not for existing SKU lines...

Comment: So what do I do instead?